# Cancel tap event on ListView after long pressing and refreshing list

Tags: android

I have an `OnLongClickListener` attached to a view within my list item view (not on the `ListView` itself). Even though I return true in the `onLongClick` callback, `onItemClick` on the `ListView` is also called once the finger leaves the screen. Normally this doesn't happen but the long press triggers a `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter which seems to reset some state and register the touch up event a new item click.

I want to prevent this additional `onItemClick` from triggering. I have tried to invalidate the views and cancel pending input events but neither did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a hacky workaround than a solution and I would love if someone could provide a better answer. In my `onLongClick` callback, I am requesting focus on the embedded view and then after 500ms, releasing that focus. This gives me the behavior I want but I would prefer not to have to rely on timing events.

```
view.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // ...
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Request focus to prevent another click event.
        view.setFocusable(true);
        view.requestFocus();

        // Release focus after a short delay.
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.setFocusable(false);
            }
        }, 500);

        return true;
    }
});
```

```

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events)

Notice that the onClick() callback in the above example has no return value, but some other event listener methods must return a boolean. The reason depends on the event. For the few that do, here's why:

- onLongClick() - This returns a boolean to indicate whether you have consumed the event and it should not be carried further. That is, return true to indicate that you have handled the event and it should stop here; return false if you have not handled it and/or the event should continue to any other on-click listeners.